# Closed set is a compact set?

Tags: general-topology

I am a beginner in topology.

I am going through the Heine-Borel theorem. The theorem says that $[a,b]$  is a compact set, where $a,b \in R$.

Is not it straight-forward that I can always construct two open sets $(a-1,b)$ and $(a, b+1)$, and both these sets are open and cover $[a, b]$, and of course its finite collection (two sets), hence $[a,b]$ is compact.

So why bother with such detailed proof of least upper bound in the proof as described in Spivak!

Comment: That would mean that $(0,1)$ would be compact.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a close vote for "needs more clarity"; the question was extremely clear. Nor am I sure why there are two downvotes; the mistake is a very common one, but that doesn't make the question bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of "compact" is that *every* open cover has a finite subcover, not that *some* open cover has a finite subcover. (Otherwise all sets would be compact in all topological spaces, because the carrier set is open.)